# Error using resource files in Sharepoint-Hosted app

Tags: resource-files, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have set a couple of supported locales in my Sharepoint-Hosted app, and now I have a folder caled "Resources (Host Web)" in my app directory. These host files contain a key/value pair WizardStep1/Teamsite Training. I added the following line in my Default.aspx file to reference it.

```
<span class="stepDesc"><small><asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:WizardStep1%>" /></small></span>
```

When I run the app I get this error:

> Sorry, something went wrong The resource object with key 'WizardStep1'
>   was not found.

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? I've used resource files in a farm solution before, but the sharepoint-hosted app seems to be different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, and that was that I was trying to use the wrong approch. For adding tranlations to the ASPX app pages, one needs to use the javascript resource file approch as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179919.aspx#LocalizingAppWeb under "How to create javascript resource files for custom pages."

Works like a charm. :)